# Sum of edge numbers for triangle given starting number, increment and number of levels

Tags: summation, triangles

For example, if starting number (N) = 1, increment (I) = 5, and number of levels (L) = 4, you get the following triangle:

`16
  11  11
 6      6
1        1`

Sum = 1 + 6 + 11 + 16 + 11 + 6 + 1 = **52**

Another example, with N = 30, I = -4, L = 3 gives:

`30      30
   26  26
     22`

Sum = 30 + 26 + 22 + 26 + 30 = **134**

If L = 1, there is only a single number in the triangle, which is N.

What equation can will give the sum of the edge and works for all: N, I (including negative), L (including 1) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$S=N+(N+I)+(N+2I)+...+[N+(L-1)I]+...+(N+I)+N=$
$\boxed{S=(2L-1)N+(L-1)^2I}$

Ex1: $S=(2.4-1).1+(4-1)^2.5=7+45=52$

Ex2: $S=(2.3-1).30+(3-1)^2.(-4)=150-16=134$

Comment: Will mark as useful when I have enough rep.

Comment: $\displaystyle S=N+(L-1)I+2\sum_{k=0}^{L-2}(N+kI)=N+(L-2)I+2\sum_{k=0}^{L-2}N+2I\sum_{k=0}^{L-2}k$

$\displaystyle S=N+(L-1)I+2N(L-1)+2I\dfrac{(L-2)(L-1)}{2}$

$$S=(2L-1)N+I(L-1)^2$$

DONE!